# AWS RDS SQL database works on localhost -- throws error from server

Tags: sql-server, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-rds

I am creating an API that calls a SQL Express database hosted on AWS RDS. When I hit an endpoint on my localhost, everything works perfectly and data is returned. I can also connect via SSMS using the same connection string from my desktop

However, after I deploy the API to Elastic Beanstalk and then call the same endpoint, I get this error:

> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server)

The instance class is set to db.t3.small.

From reading around, it looks like I need to somehow open port 1430 on the elastic beanstalk site. But I have no idea how to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like an Inbound Rule issue. You must set up inbound rules for the security group to connect to the database. You can set up one inbound rule for your development environment and another for Elastic Beanstalk (which will host the application). For information about setting up security group inbound rules, see [Controlling Access with Security Groups](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/Overview.RDSSecurityGroups.html).

Comment: Thanks! I believe you are right, but I am REALLY struggling with the details on this.

Comment: Two things to remember when working with an RDS instance from an app deployed on the Elastic Beanstalk. First, configure the RDS instance so that  Publicly accessible is true and second set the proper inbound rules.

Comment: Publicly accessible - done. It's setting inbound rules I am struggling with.

Comment: I am finding the AWS documentation to be incredibly vague! It tells you WHAT to do, but not HOW TO DO IT!!

Comment: Try getting the IP address of the App running on Elastic Beanstalk and then use that IP address when you set the Inbound rule.

Comment: Ah ha! Finally found it! Thank you for your help :)